# Pure clientside webpart for Office365

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, csom

I want to build a pure clientside (angular) webpart for my own environment. I want to have as small of a footprint as possible (So please no app domain or sandboxed solution).

It's necessairy this webpart is very easy to implement for others with custom properties available in the properties pane. (So the OOB script webpart is not an option)

Is there a possibility to do this? Or am I forced to create a sandboxed solution.

An alternative would be to create a seperate (hidden) configuration list for the javascript application (using the OOB Script webart) that's written into when the webpart is modified in page edit mode, putting the edit controls with the webpart. But again, a lot of overhead for something simple.

Comment: What's the problem with using an App?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with app development. If it's possible to create an app without an app domain and within the same page context, it's a viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this solution: [Developing Configurable Client Side Web Parts](http://almondlabs.com/blog/configurable-client-side-web-parts/)

Basically they put everything inside an OOB Script Web Part and use some logic to store the properties after edit. Editing of the properties isn't inside the edit pane, but directly inside (or above) the script web part in edit mode. I like that concept for creating that kind of configurable web parts for SharePoint online...

Comment: Unfortunately this blog is currently throwing errors.  Please answer questions with the answer rather than a link to another site.